# Installed app not found in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-2.7

Having setup the settings.py file to recognize an installed app of 'blog',

I still get this error

**No module named blog**

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http //  127dot0dot0dot1:8000 /
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named blog
Exception Location: c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  c:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['c:\\Python27\\Django-1.5\\FirstBlog',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pymysql-0.3-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'c:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'c:\\Python27',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 28 Mar 2013 16:27:11 +0530

In the shell: ImportError: No module named blog
```

But the models saves in 'blog' folder are installed on the sqlite3 db using syncdb. Any idea why this happens and how to fix this error?

Comment: your settings.py codes please

Comment: I imagen you are importing it wrong in your view or urls, can we see that code?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check `INSTALLED_APPS` section in you `settings.py` file. If `'blog',` is not added you should consider adding. After this you should proceed to `python manage.py syncdb`. Last step check your `urls.py` and see if all necessary URL mapping exists.